# Create an object with inheritance using `bless`

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance

How can I create an object of an anonymous class with inheritance using `bless`?

I guess I need to set `@ISA`, but how do I accomplish that using `strict`?

---

After a hint of райтфолд I took a look at [`Class::Inner`](http://search.cpan.org/~pdcawley/Class-Inner-0.1/Inner.pm). They solve the inheritance by

```
no strict 'refs';
@{"$anon_class\::ISA"} = $parent;
```

Is there a way to accomplish that still using strict refs?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/parent.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are playing with those things you can sometimes violate `strict`. Pragma `strict` is there to protect you from mistakes. If you are sure what you are doing it is absolutely OK to switch off `strict` in some limited scope and preferably limited to the specific thing as you have in your OP. So this code is fine when you know what you do

```
{
    no strict 'refs';
    @{"$anon_class\::ISA"} = ($parent);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`parent`](http://perldoc.perl.org/parent.html) to set the base classes for your class. `bless` has nothing to do with inheritance:

```
package Derived;
use warnings;
use strict;
use parent qw(Base);

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    return bless {}, $class;
}
```

Comment: That means that I cannot instantiate an anonymous class which inherits from another (non-anonymous) class?

Comment: @ManuelFaux See [`Class::Inner`](http://search.cpan.org/~pdcawley/Class-Inner-0.1/Inner.pm).

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there a way to accomplish that still using strict refs?*

Why? This is exactly the thing strict is designed to catch. Sure, you can fool strict, but it's far better to be clear about the fact that you are doing something strict normally forbids.

In my opinion,

```
{ no strict 'refs'; @{ $anon_class . '::ISA' } = $parent; }
```

is far better than using `eval` or `%::` (even if it they weren't longer).